# Sorting table alternating colors not showing because of divs set to display none

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here's one that I've seen before but I can't seem to get it. Basically there are two sorting filters on a table - on one of them, some of the rows that don't apply are hidden and therefore throwing off the alternating colors. Below is the code for the function that sorts, and the CSS. The page loads with the following issue as well. Any ideas? Thanks

```
//Function that sorts the table (JS and Knockout)
 orderHistoryFilterSelector = new ax.Selector($orderHistoryFilterSelector, {
  onSelect: function($link) {
    if (orderHistoryDTO) {
      filterOrderHistoryTable(orderHistoryDTO, $link);
    }
  }
});

//CSS (background on tr:nth-child(even) set to white as default)
table tbody tr:nth-child(odd) {
background-color: #f9f9f9;


//HTML - see screenshot
```

This one is the one that isn't working
[image: Doesn't work]

[image: Works] 
This one is how it's supposed to function

Answer (score 1):

You can make it to where instead of using the attribute "style" inline, have a class:

```
.hidden {
   display: none;
}
```

Add that class to the ones that are hidden then change your css rule to :

```
table tbody tr:nth-child(odd):not('.hidden') {
```